# Initiating and saving JavaScript object to a variable

Tags: javascript, oop

How can I save/reuse objects in JavaScript?

```
if (typeof window.Test == "undefined") window.Test = {};
if (typeof Test == "undefined") Test = {};

Test.Object1 = function() {
    var obj =  {

        init: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        },

        EOF: null
    };

    return obj;
}();

Test.Test = function() {
    var obj = {

        init: function() {
            var obj1 = Test.Object1.init('Object 1 initialized');
            console.log(obj1);
        },

        EOF: null
    };

    return obj;
}();

Test.Test.init();
```

`console.log(obj1)` returns `undefined`

`var obj1 = new Test.Object1();` produces `TypeError: Test.Object1 is not a constructor`

Comment: You never defined `Test`. Do you have `Test = {}` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry forgot to include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init` just calls `console.log` and returns `undefined`. You're storing the result of `init` (again, `undefined`) into `obj1` and the console is faithfully reporting that value to you.

Perhaps you want to do:

```
var obj1 = Test.Object1;
```

because `Test.Object1` has the value of `obj` inside your first anonymous function.

Or perhaps you want to do:

```
Test.Object1 = function() {
    var obj =  {

        init: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            return this;
        },
 ...
```

so that `init` returns a non-`undefined` value.

Comment: `var obj1 = Test.Object1;` is what I was looking for, I was adding `()` brackets to it, duh. Thanks!